# Divide a huge data set ( integers) into some small sets.(I have a very ugly method, seek for a nicer way)

Tags: data-visualization, python

I have a lot of integers in a file, about 45 million. I want to visualize these data, to find the distribution of these data. It's too large for a software like Mathematica to load and plot. So I use python to count up the integers in some intervals([0,1),[1,2),...,$[n,n+1)$), then use Mathematica to plot the number of the integers in each interval.  My python code is like this(there are a lot of else if(elif = else if)):

```
if x in [0,1):
     a1++
elif x in [1,2):
     a2++
......
```

It is too long and very ugly. Is there some good way to count up the integers in these intervals ?  Thanks very much .

Comment: If it's too large for Mathematica, have you tried doing the plot in R instead?

Comment: This amount of data is nowhere near too large for *Mathematica.* If indeed the file is of integers in *binary* format--as suggested by the first sentence--then *Mathematica* will read it in a few seconds and tally up the counts almost instantaneously.  The syntax would be something like `ListPlot[Tally[Import["F:/Temp/i.bin", "Integer16"]]]` depending on the actual format of the file and how the frequencies need to be visualized. If the file is not in binary format, maybe it should be ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need a long string of if-else statements, especially if your data are already integers. Something like this should work:

```
counts = {}
for integerDatum in fileData:
  try:
    counts[integerDatum] += 1
  except KeyError:
    counts[integerDatum] = 1
```

Since your file is so large that memory is an issue, you may want to stream the data in from your file in chunks and count them as you go. (How to do that will depend on the file format.)